# How do you determine if disambiguation was triggered to activate an action in Watson Assistant

Tags: watson-assistant

Currently if a user asks a question that triggers a disambiguation, and then clicks an option, I want to be able to determine if the action fired from that button (not the users input).

[image: Example of what is being described.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the variable `input.suggestion_id` to determine if disambiguation fired.

For example:

```
<? input.suggestion_id ? "Arrived to action by Disambiguation" : "Arrived directly to action" ?>
```

Generates this output.

[image: Example of output]